# How to get frequency of word in a sentence in R?

Tags: r, frequency

I have one input file which has one paragraph. I need to find the frequency of particular word in that paragraph.

cat file:

```
Text    Index
train is good   1
let the train come      5
train is best   3
i m great       3
what is best    2
```

Code:

```
 input<-read.table("file",sep="\t",header=TRUE)
 paragraph1<-input[1][1]
 word<-"train"
```

I need to find frequency of word "train" in paragraph1. How can i get it using R?

Comment: Reproducible examples are the way to go. Some effort on your behalf is also nice.

Comment: You will probably find `readLines` more useful here.

Comment: Above example is dummy example. I arlready have one variable paragraph1 in which i need to find frequency. So i cannot use readlines while reading file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you gave a little more info I could probably provide more info in return.  Using `qdap` you could:

```
library(qdap)

dat <- readLines(n=5)
train is good   1
let the train come      5
train is best   3
i m great       3
what is best    2

dat <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, strsplit(dat, "   +"))

colnames(dat) <- c("Text", "Index")

termco(dat$Text, , " train ")

## > termco(dat$Text, , " train ")
##   all word.count     train
## 1 all         16 3(18.75%)
```

You could probably do all the paragraphs at once with `termco`.  For more on `termco` see [this link](http://trinker.github.com/qdap_dev/termco.html).

Alot of this depends on what's separating paragraphs, how you're reading it in, how things are indented etc.

The poster found the following useful:

`length(gregexpr("the", "the dog ate the word the", fixed = TRUE)[[1]])`

Comment: Can I ask why?  Secondly you really need to be a lot clearer in your post with what you have, what you want.  Take note of the final line of my response and then there's mnel comments.

Comment: Reason is on my server, I don't have permission to install external package in R.

Comment: Using grep we can just check weather a text is present or not? But we cannot count the frequency of word.

Comment: I didn't say `grep`; use `?grepl`

Comment: Ok, i have data<-"train is good. But plane is better than train" if i use grepl("train",data) it gives TRUE or FALSE but not frequency.

Comment: My bad `grepl` is not your guy.  `length(gregexpr("the", "the dog ate the word the", fixed = TRUE)[[1]])`

Comment: Thankyou very much for your quick reply.

Comment: @TylerRinker if you don't want to match "them", you should use word boundaries: `length(gregexpr("\\bthe\\b", "the dog ate the word them")[[1]])`

Comment: @sebastian, good call.  I exploit this in the qdap package by supplying wors to the function with and without a space around it as I did in my original answer above.  Sometimes this behavior can be desirable as in matching `trains` and `train`.